# how does get_current_user work

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, gae-userservice

I'm really confused how Google App Engine's User's get_current_user() works. I've looked around the internet at a bunch of different guides and tutorials about login and authentication, and many of them mention similar methods.

If there are a million users logged in to my application at the same time, how can that method possibly work? Does each user get their own instance of the server? How does the server know which client it is talking to?

It doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: Wow, why the downvote? If I'm having a problem and I can't find the answer, can I not go to this website for help? Is that not the entire reason why this site exists??

Answer (score 1):

When logging in (by clicking on the URL generated by `create_login_url()`) a cookie containing user identifying information is prepared and pushed on the client side, then used in subsequent requests until the user logs out or the cookie expires. Calling `get_current_user()` simply checks the cookie existance/information and responds accordingly.

On the development server the cookie is named `dev_appserver_login`. I can no longer check the cookie name on GAE as I switched away from the Users API.

The actual handling of the cookie seems to happen somewhere on the Users service backend, for example, by looking at the `google/appengine/api/users.py` file in the python SDK:

```
def create_login_url(dest_url=None, _auth_domain=None,
                     federated_identity=None):
...
  req = user_service_pb.CreateLoginURLRequest()
  resp = user_service_pb.CreateLoginURLResponse()

  try:
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('user', 'CreateLoginURL', req, resp)
...
```

The end point (at least for the development server) seems to somehow land somewhere in `google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py`, for example:

```
  @staticmethod
  def _CreateDevAppServerCookieData(email, admin):
    """Creates cookie payload data.

    Args:
      email: The user's email address.
      admin: True if the user is an admin; False otherwise.

    Returns:
      String containing the cookie payload.
    """
    if email:
      user_id_digest = hashlib.md5(email.lower()).digest()
      user_id = "1" + "".join(["%02d" % ord(x) for x in user_id_digest])[:20]
    else:
      user_id = ""
    return "%s:%s:%s" % (email, bool(admin), user_id)

  def _DevAppServerAuthenticate(self):
    """Authenticates the user on the dev_appserver."""
    credentials = self.auth_function()
    value = self._CreateDevAppServerCookieData(credentials[0], True)
    self.extra_headers["Cookie"] = ('dev_appserver_login="%s"; Path=/;' % value)
```

Comment: where does it get the cookie from? Cookies are stored client side, but as far as I can see there is nowhere it's analyzed in the code.

Comment: I updated the answer. I don't know exactly where the API implementation checks the cookie, it's not impossible to be hapening on some backend not directly visible in the API code.